# VC2005 SP1 Redistributable x64 support on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, visual-c++, redistributable

Any idea if Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable package (x64) is supported on Windows 7 (64 bit) ?
I was able to get to this page : http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=EB4EBE2D-33C0-4A47-9DD4-B9A6D7BD44DA&displaylang=en but the supported operating systems does not include Windows 7.

Also the same question on 32 bit windows 7. Is VC++ 2005 SP1 (x86) supported on Windows 7 32 bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good rule of thumb is if it is from Microsoft and supports Vista, it probably supports Windows 7.

To be more specific, our application depends on this redistributable, and posting to you from a Windows 7 x64 machine, I can tell you that this redistributable works for me.